# show a div based on data.name

Tags: javascript, jquery

*Third time is a charm!*

This is what I am trying to achive..

I would like to use `data.name` to populate a divs ID name. I would like the `<div id="date.name"/>` to show on click, below is what I have tried.

```
  click: function(event, data) {
    $('#clicked-state')
        // .text('You clicked: '+data.name);
        .show($("<div id='" + data.name + "'/>" ));
        // .parent().effect('highlight', {color: '#C7F464'}, 2000);
  }
});
```

In this case `data.name` holds abbreviations from all 50 US states.

Once a state is clicked, *eg*. 'California' `data.name` will be assigned 'CA'.

**I want to use this to show div with id 'CA'.**

**I want to use this to display divs that I have inline with the same name.**

---

**Update: based on suggestions, div did not show onclick of state.**

Recent Attempt

*css*

```
<style>
#va { display:none;}
</style>
```

*js*

```
     click: function(event, data) {
        $('#clicked-state')
            $('#' + data.name).toggle();
      }
});
```

*html*

```
    <div id="va">
        this is virginia.
    </div>
```

**I am using this plugin for states data.name generated and map.**

http://newsignature.github.io/us-map/

Comment: Can you show more code? The html markup, perhaps? Can't understand whet #clicked-state is. And are you using jQuery?

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial to see if it helps: http://devzone.co.in/populate-state-dropdown-onchange-country-dropdown-using-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As id's in a `HTML` page are unique, you can directly use the selector to target the div and display it.

```
$('#' + data.name).show();
```

`Code`

```
click: function(event, data) {
        $('#' + data.name).show();
  }
```

Comment: I think you have typo in the code, it might still work but maybe you deleted something or forgot to delete something

Comment: This should have worked.  Try using UPPERCASE in your div `id`'s

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that .show doesn't take any parameters. I'm not 100% sure on what you're trying to do. If you're trying to show an existing div with the state name, you should call it like

```
$("#" + data.name).show();
```

If you're trying to create a new div, use .html on the parent containing div (if one doesn't exist, create one in there)

```
$("#ParentDiv").html("<div id='" + data.name + "'/>");
```

Comment: Well to be accurate `.show` can take parameters but of course not like the stuff that's in the question

Comment: Yes, excuse me. `.show` takes parameters, but not the way that the asker wants to pass them.

Answer (score 0):

Some piece of code (http://jsfiddle.net/esxe7LmL/):

```
<select>
    <option value="state1">State 1</option>
    <option value="state2">State 2</option>
    <option value="state3">State 3</option>
</select>

<div id="state1">state 1</div>
<div id="state2">state 2</div>
<div id="state3">state 3</div>


$("select").on("change", function() {
   var v = $(this).val();
    $("div").hide();
    $("div#" + v).show();
});

div {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so previous answer misunderstood the question so here's my second attempt:

```js
// remember to include your us-map.js library


$('.state').hide();

$('#map').usmap({
  // The click action
  click: function(event, data) {
    console.log( data.name );
    $(".state").hide();
    $('#' + data.name).show();    
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.2/raphael-min.js"></script>

<div id="map" style="width: 450px; height: 350px;"></div>

<div id="VA" class="state">
  This is Virginia
</div>
<div id="CA" class="state"><!-- make sure your IDs are UPPERCASE -->
  This is California
</div>
```